# Convert Military Time from text file to Standard time Python

Tags: python, time, standards

I am having problems with logic on how to convert military time from a text file to standard time and discard all the wrong values. I have only got to a point where the user is asked for the input file and the contents are displayed from the text file entered. Please help me

Comment: Why would you want to? Military time is so much nicer! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Python's [`datetime.time`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#time-objects) objects use "military" time. You can do things like this:

```
>>> t = datetime.time(hour=15, minute=12)
>>> u = datetime.time(hour=16, minute=44)
>>> t = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), t)
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 11, 15, 12)
>>> u = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), u)
>>> t - u
datetime.timedelta(-1, 80880)
```

With a little twiddling, conversions like the ones you describe should be pretty simple.

---

Without seeing any code, it's hard to tell what exactly you want. But I assume you could do something like this:

```
raw_time = '2244'
converted_time = datetime.time(hour=int(raw_time[0:2]), minute=int(raw_time[2:4]))
converted_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today(), converted_time)
```

Now you can work with `converted_time`, adding and subtracting `timedelta` objects. Fyi, you can create a `timedelta` like so:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
```

The full list of possible keyword arguments to the `timedelta` constructor is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Comment: Wait so where how does this work ? and where would this ago in terms of placement in the code?

Comment: javapro1: since you haven't provided any code, it is hard to say "where in the code" it will go.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
time_today = parse("08:00")

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
required_time = time_today-relativedelta(minutes=35)

print required_time
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 11, 7, 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a true answer like the other two, but the philosophy I use when dealing with dates and times in python: convert to a datetime object as soon as possible after getting from the user, and only convert back into a string when you are presenting the value back to the user.

Most of the date/time math you will need can be done by datetime objects, and their cousins the timedelta objects. Unless you need ratios of timedeltas to other timedeltas, but that's another story.